# Extra test types

Tags: gradle

I have a Java project that follows the standard src/main and src/test pattern, pulls in the Java plugin and works fine, except I have some very long running tests in there that I wish to pull out into an integTest sourceSet, they are integration tests really anyway.

I found an interesting article that suggested a way to do this so followed that structure, all works fine except my resources (spring config) cannot be seen when I run my new task. My additions to the build.gradle are as follows:

```
sourceSets {
    integTest {
        java.srcDir file('src/integTest/java')
        resources.srcDir file('src/integTest/resources')
    }
}

task integTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integTest.runtimeClasspath
}

task integProcessResources(type: Copy){
    from sourceSets.integTest.resources
    into sourceSets.integTest.output.resourcesDir
}

tasks.integTest.dependsOn('integProcessResources')

dependencies {
    integTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
    integTestCompile configurations.testCompile
    integTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
    integTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime
}
```

Can anyone see anything obvious that I have missed or added by mistake? I added the integProcessResources task because the files were not getting automatically copied across, even though my interpretation of the documentation was that I would not really need to do that task.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, should have mentioned I am running Gradle 2.0 with Java 1.7 on a Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

This actually tourned out not to be the problem. After trying for a while to fix this, I tried a clean and run and it was picking things up correctly, for some reason the code changes were not being identified and stuff was not being rebuild.